# webservice on android with ksoap2 too slow

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I have an android application acessing an webservice that returns a big result.
The return type, on the webservice C# server, is the type XmlElement.
My problem is, when I call it using ksoap2 on the android app, it takes a lot of time to process the result.
As the result is a xml, how can I force the ksoap to give me an String result without process it into a SoapObject?
Or there is another way to process the result more quickly?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess http get or post and sax xml parser can be used without soap. You will get faster response, smaller app size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the problem is not on the response size, but in the processing time the ksoap lib takes to put the response from xml to SoapObjects. I want just to avoid it and process the response by my self.

Comment: That's what I mean, instead of having soap on top of http, just use http get/post, then parse by yourself using your favorite parser, I found that is faster.

Comment: You right, I think this is the only way, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it in an async task and break it down to ensure the result xml is not too big. The WSDL does not matter since it is not used.

In terms of processing the xml with something else rather than using the parsed SoapObject tree:

If you do that you might as well not use KSAOP2. And you probably wont find anything faster either since KSOAP2 is already very lightweight and fast. You just use a different stack to do the same thing.