# How to call .net webservice in android using HttpClient/HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, web-services, http-post, httpclient

I have written a .net Web Service that basically connects to a remote database, queries the database and returns the records in JSON format. I have done the client side in Android to consume the web service using ksoap2 library. I found it is slow. And i found http post or http get can be used instead of SOAP from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498563/webservice-on-android-with-ksoap2-too-slow). I searched the web but i couldn't find any code snippet or step by step guide to use http post/get to call the web service. Please help me with any code snippet or step by step guide.

Answer (score 2):

Consuming JSON response is quite simple. One of my office colleague has written a blog post for beginners on "Android with WCF Services" along with demonstrated code.

Following is the code snippet from the source:

```
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // http get request
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(EMPLOYEE_SERVICE_URI
            + evEmployeeId.getText());
    // set the hedear to get the data in JSON formate
    request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    // get the response
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    // if entity contect lenght 0, means no employee exist in the system
    // with these code
    if (entity.getContentLength() != 0) {
        // stream reader object
        Reader employeeReader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                .getContent());
        // create a buffer to fill if from reader
        char[] buffer = new char[(int) response.getEntity()
                .getContentLength()];
        // fill the buffer by the help of reader
        employeeReader.read(buffer);
        // close the reader streams
        employeeReader.close();
        // for the employee json object
        JSONObject employee = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
    }
```

[LINK TO BLOG POST](http://wyousuf.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/android-with-wcf-services/)

Comment: I found the link is useful. I have a doubt.The URL of my Web Service is "http://116.12.173.121/brcfms/HelloWorldWebService.asmx". There are more than one functions in it. How do i call a particular function by sending the function name and parameter?

Comment: I'm just following the link you have sent. Here, how can i send parameters and call a particular method in the Web Service?

Comment: Something like this 
HelloWorldWebService.asmx/MethodName?ParameterName=ParameterValue

Comment: I tried that but i'm not getting any response from the server.

Answer (score -1):

I just put the URL of Web Service and it works fine :)

```
URL u = new URL("http://www.blabla.com/Webservice.svc?anyParam=hello&param2=Hahah");

HTTPURLConnection conn = (HTTPURLConnection) u.openConnection();
InputStream response = conn.getInputStream();



/* Do the rest */
```